# How does Minimum spanning tree displays the overlapping subproblem property

Tags: algorithm, tree

> The minimum spanning tree problem has both overlapping sub-problems
>   and optimal substructure.

I understood the second part of the statement , because if we consider two subtree's of MST , then the edge having the minimum weight which connects them is also in the MST.

But I didn't understand how it displays the overlapping - subproblems property , please somebody explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

To look at subproblems - that is, subgraphs - for the MST problem, you have to partition your graph by removing edges.

Along all the possible ways of taking out edges, you will encounter similar (nay, identical !) problems (i.e. sets of subgraphs), e.g. you get the same graph if you reverse the *order* in which you remove a couple of edges. Hence, if you explore all the ways to subdivide your problem, you will encounter overlapping subproblems.

(Naturally, I hope we agree this is not the way to go about finding a minimum spanning tree. I'm strictly describing the overlap in subdivisions.)

Comment: agreed that a greedy solution is a better approach.